# storing float value to unsigned char array

Tags: c, floating-point, unsigned-char

Sorry to ask this but I have searched for this small thing and found somthing related on this below link but was unable  get any idea

1. [How to store floats in array to be used later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011861/how-to-store-floats-in-array-to-be-used-later)
2. [storing in unsigned char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437849/storing-in-unsigned-char-array/2442670#2442670)

How to store a float value suppose 0.00895 to an unsigned char which is later used to store in the memory buffer.

And later I need to read the array back and want to read it back from the memory.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need (want) to store float value in unsigned char array? You can use float value. In every case it is holded in memory as chunk of bytes.

Comment: because my buffer function for storing data into memory takes its parameter as an unsigned char.I didnt get you abt float value ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `memcpy` for this...  That would be useful if you were copying a float array into a buffer elsewhere in memory.  All you really need is to use a different pointer type to look into the character array.

```
const size_t BUFSIZE = 4096;
char buffer[BUFSIZE];
float *f_buf = (float*)buffer;
```

If all you wanted was to stick a single float into the start of the buffer, either of the following two lines is okay:

```
*f_buf = 0.00895;

f_buf[0] = 0.00895;
```

All it's really doing is letting you see the buffer as an array of floats.

```
int i;

/* Put a bunch of floats into the buffer */
for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    f_buf[i] = i / 2;
}

/* Display contents of buffer in hex */
for( i = 0; i < 10 * sizeof(float); i++ ) {
    printf( "%02x", (int)buffer[i] );
}
printf( "\n" );

/* Sanity-test the buffer contents */
for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    printf( "%d: %f\n", i, f_buf[i] );
}
```

Comment: yes this looks to be what I'm searching for but I want to store the float value in an unsigned char.

Comment: You mean an *array* of `unsigned char`, right?  In that case use `unsigned char` instead of `char` in my example.  It makes no difference.  If you mean a *single* `unsigned char`, you are dreaming.  A `float` occupies four bytes, while a `char` occupies only one.

Comment: when Im trying to test buffer contents like this                                                `*f_buf = 0.00895;
check =buffer[0];       sprintf(value_current,"%f",check);       position =0x40;
Lcd_move(position);
Lcd_puts (value_current);`                                     the output is 152 but the buffer actually contains 0.00895.what is this value?

Comment: I think this is not wrkng                                        `const size_t BUFSIZE = 4096;
char buffer[BUFSIZE];
float *f_buf = (float*)buffer;`

Comment: In the hex dump, I would expect to see 80 characters (2 hex digits for each byte), but instead I see a lot more. Eg here's what I get when i run it on my machine (where a float is 4 bytes) Any idea why?:00000000000000000000ffffff803f0000ffffff803f000000400000004000004040000040400000ffffff80400000ffffff8040

Comment: OK, I figured out the problem - the bytes were being cast to ints, which can be + or -. When I replaced the cast to int with unsigned char, it printed out an 80 character string as I expected

Answer (score 3):

you can copy the memory of the float into the char buffer.

```
float a;
char buffer[sizeof(float)];
memcpy(buffer,&a,sizeof(float));
```

Comment: Can I use sprintf(value_current,"%d",buffer[0]); to see my output in the buffer 0th element.Can I be able to see the data of the buffer.